# iPad + Barcode Scanner Key Event Propagation Slow

Tags: ios, ipad, barcode-scanner, keyevent

I'm having an issue with using a bluetooth barcode scanner on my iPad running iOS 11.2. The key events are not propagating in the same order as my desktop. Windows and Mac OS do not have this issue. Has this happened to anyone else or does someone know why this is happening? I've tried Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on the iPad and they all share the same output, but the Dolphin browser works fine.

**Desktop:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzM8y.png

**iPad:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MihaF.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3rd party browsers on iOS - like Chrome, Firefox and Dolphin - *must* use WKWebView or UIWebView for rendering webpages and I'm fairly certain the speed and order of events is determined by the rendering engine.

It's not surprising to me that Chrome and Firefox both behave the same as Safari, because all three use the newer WKWebView. My best guess is that Dolphin is still using UIWebView, which is why it behaves differently. If you'd like to confirm that WKWebView is to blame, see if it works in Firefox Focus which uses UIWebView.

Unfortunately, there is not much you - or the browsers - can do about it.

Comment: Yeah I only just realized the company manufacturing the barcode scanner has a support ticket to resolve this issue, but it has been an issue since iOS 10. For now, I am just deferring the enterkey event firing by 100ms to get around the issue..

Answer (score -1):

that's because an ipad is more slower than a Desktop you cannot compare two different architectures them. Ipad always be more slower than Desktop.

Comment: It works in the Dolphin browser so I don't accept your answer.